# How to remove NaN from a Pandas Series where the dtype is a list?

Tags: python, list, pandas, numpy, nan

I've a `pandas.Series` where the dtype for each row is a list object. E.g.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x = pd.Series([[1,2,3], [2,np.nan], [3,4,5,np.nan], [np.nan]])
>>> x
0         [1, 2, 3]
1          [2, nan]
2    [3, 4, 5, nan]
3             [nan]
dtype: object
```

How do I remove the `nan` in the lists for each row?

The desired output would be:

```
>>> x
0         [1, 2, 3]
1               [2]
2         [3, 4, 5]
3                []
dtype: object
```

This works:

```
>>> x.apply(lambda y: pd.Series(y).dropna().values.tolist())
0          [1, 2, 3]
1              [2.0]
2    [3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
3                 []
dtype: object
```

Is there a simpler method than using lambda, converting to the list to a Series, dropping the `NaN` and then extracting the values back into a list again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension` with [`pandas.notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.notnull.html) for remove `NaN` values:

```
print (x.apply(lambda y: [a  for a in y if pd.notnull(a)]))
0    [1, 2, 3]
1          [2]
2    [3, 4, 5]
3           []
dtype: object
```

Another solution with `filter` with condition where `v!=v` only for `NaN`:

```
print (x.apply(lambda a: list(filter(lambda v: v==v, a))))
0    [1, 2, 3]
1          [2]
2    [3, 4, 5]
3           []
dtype: object
```

Thank you [`DYZ`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457408/how-to-remove-nan-from-a-pandas-series-where-the-dtype-is-a-list/41457495?noredirect=1#comment70121187_41457495) for another solution:

```
print (x.apply(lambda y: list(filter(np.isfinite, y))))
0    [1, 2, 3]
1          [2]
2    [3, 4, 5]
3           []
dtype: object
```

Comment: `lambda` and `if-else` conditions should be able to be simplified into `filter`, no?

Comment: @jezrael Solution with just one `lambda`: `x.apply(lambda y: list(filter(np.isfinite, y)))`.

Comment: @jezrael do u have a good resource on pandas...u seem to be an aficionado in it

Comment: what if the dtype is `pandas.core.series.Series`

Answer (score 1):

A simple `numpy` solution with list comprehension:

```
pd.Series([np.array(e)[~np.isnan(e)] for e in x.values])
```